# Setup tracking automatically, when using Gerrit

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

Everytime I push new change/branch to Gerrit:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/82-blah
```

and pull everything back (with `git pull`) I always get comment message saying:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> 82-blah
```

I don't recall seeing the same message, when pushing to non-Gerrit Git repos. Isn't something Gerrit-specific or am I missing something?

Is there any way to avoid this message (hook?), so I wouldn't have to do:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/82-blah 82-blah
```

before each pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not Gerrit specific. The tracking information can be found in the repo config file - `.git/config`. A local branch is remote tracking if there is a merge info added to the branch specific section:

```
[branch "82-blah"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/82-blah
```

So I think this info is missing in your config. How did you create the local branch that is the question. if with `git checkout -b <branch>` then there will be no tracking info added to that local branch. Better to use `git checkout -b <branch> origin/<branch>` or `git checkout <branch>`. With these commands the tracking info will be added by default. (with `--no-track` switvh it can be skipped). you can define the tracking info anytime with `git config <branch>.remote origin and git config <branch>.merge refs/heads/<branch>` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You wrote, that this isn't Gerrit specific. Interesting. I have another remote added to my local repo, called `charon`, just a simple Git, non-Gerrit remote. I created a new branch, just as usual (without extra switches you provided) then I did `git push charon --all` and then `git pull charon 82-blah` and I got `Already up-to-date` without anything about setting upstreams etc.

Comment: what config param do you have under charon remote? maybe there some common/wildcard rule for upstream

Comment: My `charon` (Git) and `origin` (Gerrit) remotes differs only in URLs and that second one has additional `push = HEAD:refs/for/master` and `fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*` added for Gerrit. Nothing unusual, I think. But I'm new to Git/Gerrit, so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: maybe the push rule is doing the unexpected behavior, try without that rule, since it is not necessary - it tells that `git push origin` will be resolved as `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

Comment: After removing the push rule, after `git pull` I'm getting the same message (about no tracking information) and after doing `git pull origin` the message is: `You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line`. All right, skip it. This seems to be either something specific to my environment or irrelevant. From now on, I'll be using `git checkout -b <branch> origin/<branch>`, as you advised, to checkout branch and set tracking information at once. Thx!

Comment: ok since git can resolve the command git push origin to git push origin master if no any additional info put into push rule. but with this push rule all the pushes will goes to master remote branch from any local branch if you use only `git push origin` - be careful. i advice to use `git push origin <local_branch>:<remote_branch>` to make it clear from where to where you want to push

Comment: This is Gerrit, right? I have to use `refs/head/[branch]` with every commit. Wouldn't that be enough for Gerrit to know, where to put my push / commit / change? I hope, it does. I don't do pushes without refs, when pushing to Gerrit.

Comment: please see this [article](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) - this is not gerrit specific at all. only if you want to push to review branch

Answer (score 1):

You can set the upstream in your first or any later pushes, so you do not have to repeat it afterwards:

```
git checkout 82-blah
git push origin -u
```